# Number of times you can vote for particular person

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I have to imagine the creators of these sites built a mechanism to detect "Vote Fraud".  Is there something to stop someone from creating two accounts and continuously vote for each other to build reputation?

Comment: You're going to have to point us to the extra accounts you're using to provide a better example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeap. It is covered in this blog entry: ["Vote Fraud and You"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/) and this one: ["More Voting anomalies"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) on blog.stackoverflow.com

Basically SO query the database from time to time and if they find that a user is just upvoting some other specific user, they all the points from that user are removed.

Comment: Basically... what?

Comment: heheh I forgot what I was going to say.. ohh yeap.. basically..

Answer (score 2):

This is called sock puppetry, and yes, there are tools to prevent it and appropriate recourse when it occurs.

Comment: I've heard Jon Skeet (aka Tony the Pony) is a master of sock puppetry. ;)

Comment: Jon Skeet's socks have a higher rep than most of us